# Flow through parallel pipes with filters present

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, water, flow

I have a system where water flow is split into two pipes, A and B. Each of A and B have a filter in the pipe. After the filter, the pipes recombine to outlet. The filters clog at different rates.

I'm very confused as to how the Bernoulli equation will relate the pressure build up at one filter as it clogs with a reduction in relative flow.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Google "pressure drop through filter cake."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick three points on the systems. point A before the pipe splits. point B in the with weak filter and point C in the strong filter.

$$B_i = P_i + \rho g h_i + \frac{1}{2} \rho v_i^2 - P_i(v)$$

where $P_i(v)$ represents the effect of the filter. It may or may not be a function of velocity.  Now we have,

$$B_A = B_B + B_C$$

and the continuity equation,

$$Q_A = Q_B + Q_C$$

If you know the effect of the filter, you should be able to solve this problem now.